# Python Flask Uploading FIles

Tags: python, firebase, flask, firebase-storage

I'm trying to upload user selected image into my firebase.

When I browse for the file

```
file = request.files['inputFile']
```

and I try this

```
storage.child("images/examples.jpg").put(file)
```

I get an error

```
io.UnsupportedOperation: fileno
```

How do I go about fixing this? I just want user to select the file and I be able to make use of the .jpg file and upload it

Answer (score 0):

The `put` method takes a path to a local file (and an optional user token).

`request.files[key]` returns a custom object that represents the uploaded file. Flask documentation links: [file uploads quickstart](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#file-uploads), [incoming request data api](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#incoming-request-data), [FileStorage class](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage).

You need to store the uploaded file data to a local file, and the pass that file name to the `put` method:

```
request.files['inputFile'].save("some_filename.ext")
storage.child("images/examples.jpg").put("some_filename.ext")
```

Look into the [`tempfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html) module to generate random temporary file names (instead of using the hard coded `some_filename.ext`, which obviously is not a very good idea with concurrent requests).